# How to implement other external login service on Meteor (i.e. loginWithWechat)?

Tags: meteor, authentication, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts, wechat

This package: https://atmospherejs.com/leonzhang1109/accounts-wechat doesn't work anymore because:

- It is outdated
- It doesn't provide way to customize the callback URL

I have implemented the wechat API parts to get a user access token and user info, this includes:

- generating QR code for user to scan
- after user scan and grant permission, access token will be obtained and be used subsequently to obtain user info.

Now the question is how do I actually login the user using the data I gather for the user such as access token, user profile id, etc.

Since there is no password, I can't user loginWithPassword, so how do I tell Meteor that this is the Meteor.currentUser() now?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use `this.setUserId` in a method to update the current user.

Comment: actually this only change the method call's userId on the server. it does not log the user in on client.